# Makefile : select files by extension, from a variable

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Is it possible to select the files from a variable that match a specific extension, and discard the rest?

```
SRCS = file1.c file2.c file3.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
OBJS += $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
```

The problem with that is that the `$(SRCS:%.c=%.o)` transforms the .c files into .o files, **but** keeps the .cpp files.

In this case, the `OBJS` variable is going to be equal to

```
file1.o file2.o file3.cpp file1.c file2.c file3.o
```

And what I want is

```
file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

So, is it possible? Or the only clean way is to have `SRCS_C` and `SRCS_CPP` variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two possible workarounds (but they'll bring you a slightly different
project organisation). First is to just have:

```
SRCS := file1 file2 file3
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=%.o)
```

Then you can define the targets using the dependencies to check either the
source file is a C or a C++ file:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $< [...]

%.o: %.c
    gcc $< [...]
```

Or you could have the object files like `file1.c.o`/`file3.cpp.o`. That means
you can have a C and a C++ file with the same name, which could be useful.
Then you would just have to do:

```
SRCS := file1.c file2.c file3.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=%.o)

%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    g++ $< [...]

%.c.o: %.c
    gcc $< [...]
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Superb. The 2nd solution is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I also think @Cakeisalie5's answer is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

With GNU make, there are several [text processing functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) available. You could try this:

```
CSRCS = $(filter %.c,$(SRCS))
CPPSRCS = $(filter %.cpp,$(SRCS))
```

This splits the list of objects in two. You can then process each individually:

```
OBJS = $(CSRCS:%.c=%.o)
OBJS += %(CPPSRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
```

Another option is to just apply two filters in one go:

```
OBJS = $($(SRCS:%.c=%.o):%.cpp=%.o)
```

This is less readable though.

Comment: I also like your second proposal and I do not think, that it is hard to read

Answer (score 0):

```
set_o_suffix=$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $1))
set_o_suffix_for_cxx=$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(filter %.c %.cpp,$1)))

SRCS := foo.c buz/bar.cpp main.js
$(info set_o_suffix=$(call set_o_suffix,$(SRCS)))
$(info set_o_suffix_for_cxx=$(call set_o_suffix_for_cxx,$(SRCS)))
all:
```

Output:

```
set_o_suffix=foo.o buz/bar.o main.o
set_o_suffix_for_cxx=foo.o buz/bar.o
```

Answer (score -3):

First of all  what kind of  OS you has?

if it Linux flavor, then you can use | grep ext

if  it window then use find | instead..

if you use file choose then while constructing the File Chooser you can fill the extension needed and sure others will be discarded...

if you run C++/C program from the command line then choose the above.

if you want variable to has specific extension then use Regular Expression 
to specify # of character after the . (dot) and allow only 1 ext.

for more info:
visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx